# Unable to connect to my C# server from an other pc

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

I have a server and a client app, the server throws no exception and seems to listen properly but the clients aren't able to connect for some reasons, I tried with both local network and public IP.

-With local network's IP I can connect to it only when the client app is runned on the same computer than the server.

-With public IP nothing can connect to the server.

However in both cases when the connection fails, it behaves always the same : waits for aproximately 5-10 seconds and then throws `System.Net.Socket.SocketException`. I tried with port 1507 first then tried with port 80 but it didn't change anything

**Server**

```
IPAddress adress = IPAddress.Parse(MyIp);
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(adress, 80);
listener.Start();
TcpClient Client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
```

**Client**

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Parse(MyIp), 80).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I don't understand where the problem comes from, is it coming from my code or not? If not the what could it be and how could I fix it?

Comment: `throws System.Net.Socket.SocketException` exception name usually doesn't say much. Please post exception details.

Comment: Have you configured the firewall on the server machine to allow HTTP access?   For access from outside your network you will likely need to do that on your router as well. (In addition to configuring port forwarding to the server IP)

Comment: @Reniuz I can't realy translate it but it says that the connection attempt failed because it hasn't answered favorably after a certain time or because the connexion's host didn't answer.

Comment: @AlexK. No i did pretty much nothing more than this code and don't know at all how my router is configured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried Telnet from outside network on specific port?
If you can't connect probably is router port redirection or access is blocked by firewall.

Comment: Telnet does same, from the pc where the server is it works otherwise it doesn't